# How to define variables while reading them from a SqlDataReader (returning all rows)

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, sqldatareader

I have a table that has 14 rows in it that i want to return as well as declare each cell as a variable. Here is what I have tried:

```
using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2012SSMS"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Question], [Answer] 
            from [MyTable]", conn1);
            conn1.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader1.HasRows)
                {
                    reader1.GetName(0);
                    reader1.GetName(1);

                    while(reader1.Read())
                    {
                        string Question(1) = reader1.GetString(0); //errors here
                        string Answer(1) = reader1.GetString(1); //and here
                    }
                    reader1.NextResult();
                }
            }
}
```

my hope is to return the declared variables as `Question1` - `Question14` and `Answer1` - `Answer14`. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You have exactly 14 questions and each question has its answer in the same row? There is no possibility to have more or less questions?

Comment: @Steve in this test no

Comment: //my hope is to return the declared variables as Question1 - Question14 and Answer1 - Answer14. //  That is not a wise thing to desire.  It's too fickle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you want to use 14 different names, you could define 14 string variables for the questions and 14 string variable for the answers. But this is frankly ridicolous when you have at your disposal Lists and other collection classes.

For example

Define a class for your question/answer

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
     public string Question {get;set;}
     public string Answer {get;set;}
}
```

then modify your code to create a `List<QuestionAnswer>`

```
List<QuestionAnswer> listOfQuestionsAndAnswers = new List<QuestionAnswer>();
using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2012SSMS"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Question], [Answer] 
                                       from [MyTable]", conn1);
    conn1.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
    {
           while(reader1.Read())
           {
               QuestionAnswer qa = new QuestionAnswer();
               qa.Question = reader1.GetString(0); 
               qa.Answer = reader1.GetString(1); 
               listOfQuestionsAndAnswers.Add(qa);
           }
    }
}
```

Now you could use any question in the List using the following syntax

```
string aQuestion = listOfQuestionsAndAnswers[0].Question;
string anAnswer = listOfQuestionsAndAnswers[0].Answer;
```

And, finally, I really suggest you to spend a bit of your time to learn how to use [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) as shown in the answer of Mr. Gravell.

Comment: It makes me very happy that somebody else also couldn't think of a better name than `QuestionAnswer` - naming stuff is hard!

Comment: Well, I have not even tried, the only thing more difficult for me is to find the proper icon for a button.

Answer (score 4):

I have *have* to give a [dapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) answer here... to show how much unnecessary code you are writing

```
public class QuestionAnswer {
    public string Question {get;set;}
    public string Answer {get;set;}
}
...
var pairs = conn1.Query<QuestionAnswer>("select Question, Answer from MyTable")
       .ToList();
```

Now: `pairs[0].Question` is the first question, and `pairs[3].Answer` is the 4th answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is return a collection of objects, where each of those objects has a `Question` and `Answer` property.

In each iteration of the loop you can create a new instance of the custom type that you have defined to hold onto these two values, and then you can add it to your data structure of choice.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a dynamic to do some thing of this nature. I have not tested the code, but conceptually this should work.

```
public class DynamicDataRecord : DynamicObject 
{
    private IDataRecord _dataRecordFromReader;

    public DynamicDataRecord(IDataRecord dataRecordFromReader) 
    { 
        _dataRecordFromReader = dataRecordFromReader; 
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out dynamic result) 
    {
        result = _dataRecordFromReader[binder.Name];
        return result != null;
    }
}
```

And then in the place you iterate through the reader you can do something like the below

```
List<DynamicDataRecord> records = new List<DynamicDataRecord>();
using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader()) 
{
    foreach(var record in reader)
    {
        records.Add( new DynamicDataRecord(record));
    }
}
```

And then you should be able to do something like this.

```
records[0].Question

record[0].Answer
```

Comment: And where does the row data get into the `DynamicDataRecord`?